# How to prevent app choosing dialog?

Tags: android, keyevent, keycode, dispatch, key-events

When I get `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MUSIC` from a remote controller the OS automatically opens a dialog with a suitable apps that can handle the intent. I want to know is that possible to do not let the dialog appear at all ?

The intenet code:

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"   />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.example.aram.keycontrol.MediaButtonIntentReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: How's your intent code?

Comment: have updated the question

Comment: I don't think you can. The key would be pressed outside of your app so you don't create the Intent yourself.